# Implementing Google Sign in for iOS (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, swift

I have read few threads on this, but none has addressed by problem. I am trying to implement Google Sign in for iOS following the steps mentioned by Google developer [portal](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#enable_sign-in).

When I add the following 2 delegate method as mentioned in Google developer portal in my code, I am unable to compile the source.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey],
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication,
            UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation]
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

Here is the error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Read a beginner book about Swift. Each an every book covers optionals.

Comment: learn about optionals http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 func application(application: UIApplication,
openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool
{
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication:   options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}


func application(application: UIApplication,
openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
}
```

for sample see [this](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-google-signin-sdk-in-ios-application-using-swift)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Anbu

Comment: Worked with some minor change: func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool
    {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication:   options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
        }
        
        return false
    }

Comment: oh are you checked the `if #available(iOS 9.0, *`, any way welcome bro